# Since SELECT FOR UPDATE is meaningless without a transaction and transactions use locks by itself, what is the usecase of SELECT FOR UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, select-for-update

From here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27868682/10894456

> SELECT ... FOR UPDATE will lock the record with a write (exclusive)
>   lock until the transaction is completed (committed or rolled back).
>
> To select a record and ensure that it's not modified until you update
>   it, you can start a transaction, select the record using SELECT ...
>   FOR UPDATE, do some quick processing, update the record, then commit
>   (or roll back) the transaction.

and here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411366/10894456

> note that FOR UPDATE outside of a transaction is meaningless

So since INSERT FOR UPDATE is meaningless without a transaction & transactions use locks by itself, what is the usecase of INSERT FOR UPDATE?
My only guess: 
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE makes sense only if transaction has a low isolation level ( like read_uncommit), but I'm not sure, help me please

Answer (score 0):

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16963718/10894456

> The main difference between SERIALIZABLE and using SELECT FOR UPDATE
>   is that with SERIALIZABLE everything is always locked. Where as with
>   SELECT FOR UPDATE you get to choose what and when you lock.

So SELECT FOR UPDATE allows us to be picky